# My 3 year old will not fall asleep without me in the room. How can I break this?

Tags: toddler, sleep, crying

My 3 year old daughter will not sleep unless someone is in the room with her and when she doesn't want to go to sleep and finally does and wakes up and we're not in there she cries and doesn't go back to sleep at all.  I really want to break her of this routine but I'm not sure how.  Last night, for example, she would not go to sleep. She finally fell asleep at 1am and so I snuck out and went to my bed and she woke up at 1:30 and stayed awake all night.  I asked her why she wouldn't go to sleep and she said just because I don't want to.  Please help!

Comment: Some resources for you. http://scienceofmom.com/2014/07/29/getting-our-3-year-old-back-to-good-sleep-in-9-not-easy-steps/

Comment: @Sabrina Sounds like your daughter is my son's twin!  Hopefully the linked question is helpful - if it's not, edit the question to clarify where your particular issue is different.  Good luck!

Comment: http://www.thesleepstore.co.nz/sleep-information/toddlers/sleep-articles/gently-train-your-toddler-to-sleep

Comment: @joe. I don't see a link from you.

Comment: Linked questions show up over to the right under "Linked" - or in this case is in Erica's comment.

Comment: To me this speaks _insecurity_, and I doubt you can "break her out" of that. I suspect only constant long-term reassurance can help to make her feel more secure. Does your daughter sleep in her own room? It seems she doesn't want to. How about putting her bed into your sleeping room? Besides yours? Or try adding an extension to your bed so she can snuggle against you, and at the same time you can shove her off when you need to sleep yourself without a toddler's foot in your stomach.